How to propagate SAXExcetion while validating xml using javax.xml.validation.Validator
  public boolean validateXML() throws Exception {
        sepaRTLogger.info("Entered validateXML()");
        Schema schema = listOfXSDs.get(xmlVersion);
        sepaRTLogger.debug("matched schema:::" + schema);
        System.out.println("matched schema:::" + schema);
        
        try {
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate((Source) (new StreamSource(XMLStreamForValidation)));
        } catch (Exception e){
            if(e instanceof IOException) {
                sepaRTLogger.error("IOException error:",e);
            }
            if(e instanceof SAXException){
                sepaRTLogger.error("SAXException error:",e);
                retriggerException.reThrow(msgTagID, null, new SAXException(), e.getMessage(), "TFLT101");
            }
            throw new Exception( e);
        }finally{
            XMLStreamForValidation.close();
        }

        return true;
    }


sepaRTLogger.error("SAXException error:",e);
retriggerException.reThrow(msgTagID, null, new SAXException(), e.getMessage(), "TFLT101");

Line 1 is printing error but excetion become null in line 2. So not able to propagate this excetion.

catch (Throwable e) {
  throw (RuntimeException) e;
}

Actually, catch(Throwable) will catch everything including Errors and checked exceptions(SAXException). Also Checked Exception can be put try...catch block where RuntimeException has an Exception super Class soIs it can bepossibe to propagate. checked exception?

Issue is resolved . Thanks !
